# How to find F(x,0) when F(x,i) = F(x-1,i) xor F(x-1, i+1) xor ... F(x-1,n) in less than linear time

Tags: recursion, bit-manipulation, sequence, series, xor

Given a base array, I need to compute the value of a function given below:

```
A[] = { a0, a1, a2, a3, .. an }

F(0,i) = ai  [Base case] 

F(1,i) = F(0,i) xor F(0,i+1) xor F(0,i+2) ... xor F(0,n)
F(2,i) = F(1,i) xor F(1,i+1) xor F(1,i+2) ... xor F(1,n)
.
.
F(x,i) = F(x-1,i) xor F(x-1,i+1) xor F(x-1,i+2) ... xor F(x-1,n)

0 < x < 10^18
0 < n < 10^5
```

I need to find **F(x,0)**.

I am trying to solve this equation for the past 3 days. I have failed to optimise it and come up with a feasible solution. Any help to find F(x,0) in less than linear time is appreciated.

My observation (if it is of any importance) :

```
F(0,0) = a0
F(1,0) = a0^a1^a2^a3 ....
F(2,0) = a0^a2^a4 ....
F(3,0) = (a0^a4^a8...) ^ (a1^a5^a9...)
F(4,0) = a0^a4^a8 ....
F(5,0) = (a0^a1^a2^a3) ^ (a8^a9^a10^a11) ^ (a16^..a19) ^ ...
F(6,0) = (a0^a8^a16...) ^ (a2^a10^a18...)
F(7,0) = (a0^a8^a16...) ^ (a1^a9^a17...)
F(8,0) = a0^a8^a16^ ....
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog The OP is asking for an algorithm that solves the problem in linear time, not claiming that the recursive function has linear complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it becomes easier if you reverse the array, with the recurrence relation

```
F(0, i) = a[n-i]
F(x, i) = XOR[0 <= j < i]( F(x-1, j) )
```

that is, going from 0 to i instead of i to n. We are then looking for `F(x, n)`. If we make a table:

```
  | 0        1           2                              3
--+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 | A=a[n]   B=a[n-1]    C=a[n-2]                       D=a[n-3]
1 | A        A^B         A^B^C                          A^B^C^D
2 | A        A^(A^B)     A^(A^B)^(A^B^C)                A^(A^B)^(A^B^C)^(A^B^C^D)^B^C^D
3 | A        A^(A^(A^B)) A^(A^(A^B))^(A^(A^B)^(A^B^C))  A^(A^(A^B))^(A^(A^B)^(A^B^C))^(A^(A^B)^(A^B^C)^(A^B^C^D))
```

or let's stop using the XOR sign and just count how often each term appears:

```
  | 0   1     2        3           4
--+-----------------------------------------------
0 | 1A    1B       1C          1D             1E
1 | 1A  1A1B   1A1B1C   1A 1B1C1D   1A 1B 1C1D1E
2 | 1A  2A1B   3A2B1C   4A 3B2C1D   5A 4B 3C2D1E
3 | 1A  3A1B   6A3B1C  10A 6B3C1D  15A10B 6C3D1E
4 | 1A  4A1B  10A4B1C  20A10B4C1D  35A20B10C4D1E
```

We can also see that the recurrence relation is the same as

```
F(x, i) = F(x-1, i) + F(x, i-1)
```

This is [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle). Specifically, the values we are after are the *n*th diagonal, which can of course be [calculated on its own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself). Then check whether the number is even or odd, so that you know whether the XOR operations on that element cancel themselves out or not.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understood till the table creation, equivalent recurrence, use of Pascal's triangle & that F[x,n] will contain the value I am looking for. But I didn't understand how to compute this value in less than O(n). Can you please explain how to find F[x,n] in less than O(n)..

Comment: @SwastikSahu I don't know how you think that's possible. Consider that `F(1,n)` has to XOR *all* `n` elements of the array - you cannot get better than linear. Of course, the algorithms complexity does not depend on `x` at all - it's constant in that regard. I think that `O(x⁰n¹)` is a really good complexity already.

Comment: Using Pascal's triangle we can compute F(x,n) in O(n) time.. but if there are n queries, the total complexity becomes O(n^2). This same as computing F(x,n) from F(x-1,n). I have observed that the values of F(x,n) have a periodicity = least pow of 2, greater that or equal to n, ie - F(x,4) = F(x+4, 4); F(x,5) = F(x+8, 5). So we will only need to precompute values for x: 1 to least pow of 2 >= n. Precomputation will take O(n^2). Queries can be answered O(1). But O(n^2) is too much when n = 10^5

Comment: You never talked of `n` queries? Of course you can memoise the triangle if you have multiple calls to the function.

Comment: Oh, the article [goes on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#Overall_patterns_and_properties): "*The pattern obtained by coloring only the odd numbers in Pascal's triangle closely resembles […] the Sierpinski triangle.*" By exploiting that with a periodic pattern, we might indeed get the average complexity for calculating the evenness of a row down to `O(n/x+x)`.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain how can eveness of rowbe calculated in O(n/x+x). I suppose you might be creating buckets but i cant think how to use them to get answer

Comment: @monster I suppose it's actually `O(n * relativeDensity(x) + x)`. You'd have to check what the pattern in diagonal x is (the pattern has at most length `x`), then you only go for the odd elements of the pattern over the whole n. Of course this buys you nothing if `n < x`, and has no advantage over the naive `O(n)` solution when all elements in the pattern are odd.

Comment: @Bergi I think it is still a O(n^2) solution as we need to go and check if it is even or odd.

Comment: @user3243499 Checking whether an element is odd is `O(1)`, not `O(n)`

Comment: no, I mean, if I need to go literally to every elements on the kth Pascal's diagonal and check for odd values and it is F(x,n) then it would take O(n) to find F(x,n). And then if it is asked to find n numers, then we would need to parse every n diagonals which makes overall complexity of O(n^2)

Comment: @user3243499 "*if it is asked to find n numers*" - but it wasn't, or at least no further information was given about that. If all those `x`s are different with no patterns, there's nothing but the naive approach.