# How to simulate xor of sets using bitwise operators?

Tags: set, bit-manipulation

I have 5 sets: s0, s1, s2, s3, s4 such that

```
s0 = {0,1,2,3,4}
s1 = {1,2,3,4}
s2 = {2,3,4}
s3 = {3,4}
s4 = {4}
```

NOTE: Next set will follow that order. And elements [0,5) in them are nothing but indices of another array. So the elements would never exceed 4 if the are representing indices of an array with size 5.

Now, I want to perform XOR operation of some of these sets to find new set of indices to access array elements.

I can perform normal set XOR operations here, but that seems time consuming.

So, is it possible to get the next set of indices after XORing some of the given sets?

**Update:**

For example,

```
let's assume, initially, snew_set = {0,2,4}
snew_set = s0 ^ s2 ^ s4 = {0,1,4}
snew_set = s0 ^ s1 ^ s4 = {0,4}
snew_set = s0 ^ s4 = {0,1,2,3}
```

and soon.

The above is a recursive pattern which depends on its previous set values. Is there any other efficient way to calculate the next snew_set rather than literally finding common elements one by one?

**NOTE:** Elements in the set, that is  `{0,1,2,3,4......., (n-1)} are limited by n`

Comment: i cant get what you need from the data provided.can you give an example of what you want to do? PS- jst a guess but i think you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090710/how-to-find-fx-0-when-fx-i-fx-1-i-xor-fx-1-i1-xor-fx-1-n-in-le

Comment: @monster I have updated the problem description with an example.